# Doing a post on spring boot olingo on an entity with a relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, odata, olingo

I have some odata V2 apis built from spring-boot and olingo. I'm trying to a post to an entity with a relationship

```
public class CompanyProfileDetail {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Long version;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_profile_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CompanyProfile companyProfile;
...
}

public class CompanyProfile {

    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private Long version;

...
}
```

So when I try to post this using the CompanyProfileDetails api

```
{
    "Version": "1",
    "CompanyProfile": "1"
}
```

it doesn't work but this

```
{
    "Version": "1",
    "CompanyProfileDetails" : {
        "__metadata": {
                "id": "http://localhost:8080/odata/CompanyProfiles(1L)",
                "uri": "http://localhost:8080/odata/CompanyProfiles(1L)",
                "type": "default.CompanyProfile"
            }
    }
}
```

works. So now I'm wondering if this is an odata standard of posting with relationships or is there some setting that will accept the first structure.

FYI the "CompanyProfileDetails" in the second data structure is how olingo automatically names the related entity. It's actually the CompanyProfiles entity

As another example:

```
public class CompanyProfile {

    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private Long version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Location address;

    @Column(name="contact_number")
    private String contactNumber;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;
...
}

public class Location {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NotNull
    private Long id;


    private Long version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CityMunicipality city;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "province", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Province province;
}
```

The working request looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "1",
    "ContactNumber": "1245",
    "Name": "OIL Tycoon corporation",
    "Status": "OK",
    "LocationDetails" : {
        "__metadata": {
                "id": "http://localhost:8080/odata/Locations(2L)",
                "uri": "http://localhost:8080/odata/Locations(2L)",
                "type": "default.Location"
            }
    }
}
```

However this does not work:

```
{
    "Version": "1",
    "ContactNumber": "1245",
    "Name": "OIL Tycoon corporation",
    "Status": "OK",
    "Address" : "2",
}
```

Location with an Id of 2 exists in this case.

As requested the $metadata. This is for the second example. Hope this helps!

```
<EntityType Name="CompanyProfile">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id"></PropertyRef>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Address" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="true"></Property>
                <Property Name="ContactNumber" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="255"></Property>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"></Property>
                <Property Name="Version" Type="Edm.Int64"></Property>
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"></Property>
                <NavigationProperty Name="LocationDetails" Relationship="default.CompanyProfile_Location_Many_ZeroToOne0" FromRole="CompanyProfile" ToRole="Location"></NavigationProperty>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="Location">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id"></PropertyRef>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="City" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"></Property>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false"></Property>
                <Property Name="Province" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true"></Property>
                <Property Name="Region" Type="Edm.Region" Nullable="true"></Property>
                <Property Name="Version" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="true"></Property>
</EntityType>
```

Comment: Here one to one mapping makes real sense when we have in company profile and not in company profile detail.

Comment: Ah this is just a simplified version to show how the relationship was made in code. Also, the CompanyProfile in this case is already existing. I'm not creating a new CompanyProfile, I'm only setting it to CompanyProfildeDetails.

Comment: Do not club all attributes in one json. the attributes which has relation should be a child json. You can refer my answer and try that format. Hope that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Default Implementaion of Olingo 2.0 JPA processor names the Navigation properties in the format `<Navigation Property Name>Details` , so for example if you have a join named `Location` the navigation property will be named as `LocationDetails`

To perform the DeepInset you can use the following payload

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "contactNumber" : "",
    "LocationDetails": {
        "id":"",
        "version":"",
         "CityMunicipalityDetails":{
             // all attributes of city class
          },
         "ProvinceDetails":{
            // all attributes of province class
          }
    
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also look at the implementation of `$batch` in OData 2 as Deep inserts were part of Later Version of OData Implementations but Olingo 2.0 JPA Processor implemented in version 2.0 also.

PS: Please check the `$metadata` for the navigation property names and if possible post the `$metadata` content if this solution doesn't solves the issue.

Comment: Sorry @Shiva I forgot to ask this earlier. As a follow up question, is this a quirk of Spring-boot snd/or olingo? And is there anyway to change it so that it will also accept the format of just directly putting the id like "Address" : "2"?

Comment: This is Olingo and OData and has nothing to do with Spring Boot. To create entities in a disjoint fassion I would suggest looking at $batch way to create entities

Answer (score 0):

You have specified two post request which is not working. For the first one, below request body should work.

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "companyProfile": {
        "id" : 1,
        "version" : "1"
    
    }
}
```

For the second one,

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "contactNumber" : "",
    "address": {
        "id":"",
        "version":"",
         "city":{
             // all attributes of city class
          },
         "province":{
            // all attributes of province class
          }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Karthick, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I'm getting a malformed body error. Just to be sure, isn't this method going to create those in the sub-object as well? I tried only using the Id inside in my case since I'm trying to create a relationship instead of creating the sub-object. I'm not entirely sure what the standards of odata are in this case though. I should add that this is an odata api. I just added that to the tags as well.

Comment: Please post the api method which receives the request. Between you can also go through this link and comments to see how request is posted.

https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-one-mapping-example/