# odata create entity with one to many relationship

Tags: post, odata, one-to-many, olingo

In Odata create entity i am having one to many relationship, with below request json am getting,

```
{
   "parentProperty1":"",
   "parentProperty2":"",
   "parentProperty3":"",
   "NavigationProperty":[
      {
         "childProperty1":""
      }
   ]
}
```

Error

```
org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.api.exception.ODataJPARuntimeException: "OData - JPA Runtime: JPA create request is not correct" 
   at org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.api.exception.ODataJPARuntimeException.throwException(ODataJPARuntimeException.java:100 undefined) ~[olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12] 
   at org.apache.olingo.odata2.jpa.processor.core.access.data.JPALink.linkJPAEntities(JPALink.java:242 undefined) ~[olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core-2.0.12.jar:2.0.12
```

Comment: Do you get an `innererror` as shown in [this example](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-293)?

Comment: @AxelKemper No I didnt get any inner error mentioned in the Jira

Comment: Is there any sample json for createEntity call?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109329/doing-a-post-on-spring-boot-olingo-on-an-entity-with-a-relationship/63123546#63123546 , might help